# amazon-ivs-web-broadcast - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bind')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror, undefined, amazon-ivs

Working with amazon-ivs-web-broadcast and running into the issue mentioned above when trying to create the IVSBroadcastClient

```
import IVSBroadcastClient from "amazon-ivs-web-broadcast";

let client = IVSBroadcastClient.create({
    streamConfig: IVSBroadcastClient.BASIC_LANDSCAPE,
    ingestEndpoint: streamConfigData?.stream_url,
})
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa7bS.png)

Any ideas what may be causing this?

Tried passing hard coded values as arguments, and still running into the same error, so not sure what else could be causing this.

EDIT: This issue works fine on my local instance, but when it gets deployed to development, only then I am seeing the error mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using React for this application (since I have seen this issue myself with React). If so, for now, you'll have to produce your production build with the following command:

`npm run build -- --profile`

To workaround an issue with the way function names are minified.

Comment: Yes, using React. I was able to resolve the issue by using an older version of the package, but will keep this in mind as well. Thanks, Todd!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to the latest version of the library (1.3.0 or greater) and this is fixed.